# How to delete all the lines in one go in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to delete all the lines below a particular line of emacs ? Is there **any shortcut key** which can delete all the lines below a particular line?

Comment: You are kind of missing the point of using a programmable, extensible editor if you want to restrict yourself to predefined key bindings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`C-u 9999999 C-k` should do the trick.

If you are not at the beginning of the first line you want to kill, then use `C-a C-u 9999999 C-k`.

(The `9999999` can be any number larger than the number of lines you want to kill.)

An alternative to using `C-u 999999` is to hold down the `Control` key and then hold down `9`, so you get, in effect: `C-9 C-9 C-9 C-9 C-9 C-9 C-9 C-k`.

Comment: Try again. Unless you have something in your init file (`~/.emacs`) that changes things it will work. To be clear, `C-a` means press and hold `Control` while hitting `a`, and so on.

Comment: actually the number 1000 was being displayed as 1 0 0 0 so i thought it was working for single digits but that was not the case and it deleted 1000 lines

Comment: Using `9`s instead of `1`s and `0`s means fewer keystrokes. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Just add this function to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(defun kill-to-end-of-buffer() "Deletes all lines after the current line"
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (forward-line 1)
    (delete-region (point) (point-max))))


;; Change this to your preferred keybinding
(global-set-key "\C-\M-k" 'kill-to-end-of-buffer)
```

Comment: Incredibly convenient. Thank you!